# Нужна ли запятая? Союз "что"

Tags: пунктуация

*"Помни что ты не опаздываешь"* или *"Помни, что ты не опаздываешь"*? Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, запятая нужна, поскольку это типичное СПП. Оно полностью соответствует описанию на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), и Ваш пример очень похож на приведённый там: *«Я знаю, кто это сделал».* **Кто/что** и **пов. накл. / 1-е лицо** погоды не делают.